# Trying to get current_date in epoch format in a variable

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to get `current_date` in epoch format in an Oracle PL/SQL variable:

```
DECLARE 
    start_date VARCHAR2(12);
    end_date VARCHAR2(12);
    start_epochtime VARCHAR2(15);
    end_epochtime VARCHAR2(15);
BEGIN
    SELECT '''' || to_char(current_date,'YYYY-MM-DD') || '''' into start_date from dual ;  --  '2016-01-20'
    SELECT '''' || to_char(current_date - 30,'YYYY-MM-DD') || '''' into end_date from dual ; -- '2015-12-21'
    dbms_output.put_line(start_date);
    dbms_output.put_line(end_date);
    /* Below section will convert date to epochtime with hard code date value*/
    SELECT '''' || (CAST((TO_DATE('2016-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') - TO_DATE('1970-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') ) * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 AS VARCHAR(15))) || '''' into start_epochtime FROM DUAL;
    SELECT '''' || (CAST((TO_DATE('2016-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') - TO_DATE('1970-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') - 30) * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 AS VARCHAR(15))) || '''' into end_epochtime FROM DUAL;
    dbms_output.put_line(start_epochtime);
    dbms_output.put_line(end_epochtime);
    /* Below section will convert date to epochtime with a variable and it is not working */
    SELECT '''' || (CAST((TO_DATE(start_date,'YYYY-MM-DD') - TO_DATE('1970-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') ) * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 AS VARCHAR(15))) || '''' into start_epochtime FROM DUAL;
    SELECT '''' || (CAST((TO_DATE(end_date,'YYYY-MM-DD') - TO_DATE('1970-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') - 30) * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 AS VARCHAR(15))) || '''' into end_epochtime FROM DUAL;
    dbms_output.put_line(start_epochtime);
    dbms_output.put_line(end_epochtime);
END;

SQL>
'2016-03-02'
'2016-02-01'
'1451606400000'
'1449014400000'
DECLARE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0
ORA-06512: at line 17
```

Comment: Please take the time to [format your question properly](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). The [tags](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) you have used are not appropriate either; [tag:oracle] and [tag:plsql] would have been better, and would have given your question more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the single quotes you are putting around the variable value. String literals need those, but a string variable does not. It is already a string, you do not need quotes to indicate that.

In your final conversions you're doing the equivalent of;

```
select TO_DATE('''2016-01-01''','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual;
```

which gets the same ORA-01841.

If you strip out all the extra quotes you get:

```
DECLARE 
  start_date VARCHAR2(12);
  end_date VARCHAR2(12);
  start_epochtime VARCHAR2(15);
  end_epochtime VARCHAR2(15);
BEGIN
  SELECT to_char(current_date,'YYYY-MM-DD') into start_date from dual;
  SELECT to_char(current_date - 30,'YYYY-MM-DD') into end_date from dual;
  dbms_output.put_line(start_date);
  dbms_output.put_line(end_date);
  /* Below section will convert date to epochtime with hard code date value */
  SELECT CAST((TO_DATE('2016-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') - TO_DATE('1970-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') ) * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 AS VARCHAR(15)) into start_epochtime FROM DUAL;
  SELECT CAST((TO_DATE('2016-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') - TO_DATE('1970-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') - 30) * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 AS VARCHAR(15)) into end_epochtime FROM DUAL;
  dbms_output.put_line(start_epochtime);
  dbms_output.put_line(end_epochtime);
  /* Below section will convert date to epochtime with a variable */
  SELECT CAST((TO_DATE(start_date,'YYYY-MM-DD') - TO_DATE('1970-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') ) * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 AS VARCHAR(15)) into start_epochtime FROM DUAL;
  SELECT CAST((TO_DATE(end_date,'YYYY-MM-DD') - TO_DATE('1970-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') - 30) * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 AS VARCHAR(15)) into end_epochtime FROM DUAL;
  dbms_output.put_line(start_epochtime);
  dbms_output.put_line(end_epochtime);
END;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
2016-03-02
2016-02-01
1451606400000
1449014400000
1456876800000
1451692800000
```

Incidentally, you don't need all the context switches to select from dual, you can assign the result of most functions directly to PL/SQL variables:

```
...
BEGIN
  start_date := to_char(current_date,'YYYY-MM-DD');
  end_date := to_char(current_date - 30,'YYYY-MM-DD');
  dbms_output.put_line(start_date);
  dbms_output.put_line(end_date);
  /* Below section will convert date to epochtime with hard code date */
  start_epochtime := TO_CHAR((DATE '2016-01-01' - DATE '1970-01-01') * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
  end_epochtime := TO_CHAR((DATE '2016-01-01' - DATE '1970-01-01' - 30) * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
  dbms_output.put_line(start_epochtime);
  dbms_output.put_line(end_epochtime);
  /* Below section will convert date to epochtime with a variable */
  start_epochtime := TO_CHAR((TO_DATE(start_date,'YYYY-MM-DD') - DATE '1970-01-01') * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
  end_epochtime := TO_CHAR((TO_DATE(end_date,'YYYY-MM-DD') - DATE '1970-01-01' - 30) * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
  dbms_output.put_line(start_epochtime);
  dbms_output.put_line(end_epochtime);
END;
/
```

which gets the same output.

---

In a comment you said you're doing:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
  "select to_char((TO_DATE('1970-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd') + (m.CREATIONDATE/1000/24/60/60)),'YYYY-MM-DD'),count(1) 
  from jivemessage_us m 
  where m.CREATIONDATE >= :start_epochtime 
     and m.CREATIONDATE < :end_epochtime 
  group by to_char((TO_DATE('1970-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd') + (m.CREATIONDATE/1000/24/60/60)),'YYYY-MM-DD') 
  order by 1";
```

That has the dynamic statement enclosed in double-quotes. Oracle uses those for identifiers (i.e. object and column names). Your statement needs to be enclosed in single quotes. But that means all the single quotes you already have in the statement need to be escaped by doubling them up, which is messy, or you can use [the alternative quoting mechanism](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00218):

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
 q'[select to_char((TO_DATE('1970-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd') + (m.CREATIONDATE/1000/24/60/60)),'YYYY-MM-DD'),count(1) 
   from jivemessage_us m 
   where m.CREATIONDATE >= :start_epochtime 
       and m.CREATIONDATE < :end_epochtime 
   group by to_char((TO_DATE('1970-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd') + (m.CREATIONDATE/1000/24/60/60)),'YYYY-MM-DD') 
   order by 1]';
```

You might want to split that on to multiple lines to make it more readable, and use date literals to make it shorter. You also need a `using` clause to supply the bind values, and it needs to select *into* something - either two scalar variables or a record type, or as it can find multiple dates a collection type.

Depending on what you do with the results you might also want to keep the result as a date rather than a string.

This doesn't need to be a dynamic statement at all though. You know everything you need to for this to be static SQL, possibly:

```
select trunc(DATE '1970-01-01' + (m.CREATIONDATE/1000/24/60/60)), count(*)
bulk collect into ... -- table of records
from jivemessage_us m
where m.CREATIONDATE >= start_epochtime
and m.CREATIONDATE < end_epochtime
group by TRUNC(DATE '1970-01-01' + (m.CREATIONDATE/1000/24/60/60));
```

Or if you just plan to loop over the results you can use that as a query, without needing a bulk collect or a collection type.

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks for your update. Also i am trying to use that variable in the below query and it throws an error.                                                       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE "select to_char((TO_DATE('1970-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd') + (m.CREATIONDATE/1000/24/60/60)),'YYYY-MM-DD'),count(1) from jivemessage_us m where m.CREATIONDATE >= :start_epochtime and m.CREATIONDATE < :end_epochtime group by to_char((TO_DATE('1970-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd') + (m.CREATIONDATE/1000/24/60/60)),'YYYY-MM-DD') order by 1";
 22  
 23  END;
 24  /
ERROR:
ORA-00972: identifier is too long

Comment: @RajiniRajas it's really hard to read code in comments. But you're using double-quotes (`"`) around the dynamic statement, so the entire thing is being seen as an identifier, hence the error. Your statement should be a string literal, which also means any single quotes inside it need to be escaped, or you can use the alternative quoting mechanism.